# How to read/write .dat file within Jar file?

Tags: java

Okay this maybe very similar to a few questions out there and I've been looking all over, but can't manage to fix this. This is the only thing preventing my .jar from compiling properly so I would love to get this fixed.

**I have a highScores.dat file that I need to read and write on within the .jar, but I can't get the Input and Output Streams to accept a path, only a filename**, which doesn't make sense to me.

Here's the method's I'm using:

```
public class HighScoreManager {
  private File fileName = new File("highScores.dat");

public void addScore(String playerName, int score) {
    loadScoreFile();
    scores.add(new Score(playerName, score));
    updateScoreFile();
}

public void loadScoreFile() {
    try {
        inputStream = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(fileName));
        scores = (ArrayList<Score>) inputStream.readObject();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("File not found: " + e.getMessage());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("IO Error: " + e.getMessage());
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("Class not found: " + e.getMessage());
    } finally {
        try {
            if (outputStream != null) {
                outputStream.flush();
                outputStream.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("IO Error: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}

public void updateScoreFile() {
    try {
        outputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(fileName));
        outputStream.writeObject(scores);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("File not found: " + e.getMessage());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("IO Error: " + e.getMessage());
    } finally {
        try {
            if (outputStream != null) {
                outputStream.flush();
                outputStream.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Update Error: " + e.getMessage());
        }}}}
```

The path is /highScores/highScores.dat which should be correct since images that are located in /images/ work fine with my buffered images within the .jar

**Edit:** Changing the filename to a path doesn't work. I've also tried getClass().getResourceAsStream to no avail.

Comment: What is the exception/error you get?

Comment: `ZippFile epub = new ZipFile(filePath);`
`ZipEntry entry = epub.getEntry("META-INF/container.xml");`
`InputStream in = epub.getInputStream(entry);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get an `InputStream` using `Class.getResourceAsStream` (or `ClassLoader`) using a class or `ClassLoader` that "knows" about that jar file.

If you're finding that `Class.getResourceAsStream()` isn't working for you, you're probably passing in the wrong resource name. It's case-sensitive even on Windows, and relative to the class you call it on unless you use a leading `/`.

However, you can't easily *write* to a jar file in that way - you can build a complete new jar file using `JarOutputStream`, but I suspect you don't want to do that. I'd use a separate file, personally - you can always see if that exists and read from the jar file otherwise.

Comment: What would be the correct way of implementing that into FileInputStream? I've been trying some variations but not sure what it's looking for. inputStream = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/highScores/highScores.dat")));

Comment: @FroZenL1Qu1d: No, it just *isn't* a `FileInputStream` - the resource doesn't exist as a file in the normal file system. Just pass the `InputStream` returned by `getResourceAsStream` straight into the `ObjectInputStream` constructor.

Comment: Ah okay, now it loads the highscores properly in the .jar but doesn't seem to write into the file, although no errors are given. I assume no simple way of doing that then?

Comment: @FroZenL1Qu1d: Well I suspect it's writing to somewhere you don't expect. You should look at `fileName.getCanonicalPath()`

Comment: You're right, it says file not found at \highScores\highScores.dat. Not sure how I should modify it, since that is supposedly the correct path. Or does that mean it's not looking inside the .jar after all? Can't use the same method either, since it's an input stream.

Comment: @FroZenL1Qu1d: You said it was the *writing* that doesn't work - and that doesn't use an input stream at all. I'm very confused - I suggest that now you've got the reading working, you post a new question with your new situation.

Comment: I guess I could. I mean I have that FileNotFound exception on updateScoreFile() and that's where it says not found. I guess my FileOutputStream is faulty, as I just use the path String on it.